# Selecting a set of parameters based on input value in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am working on a Module which changes it's constant values based on the input  to calculate it's output.

Let me illustrate what I am looking for,

Let x be the input, y the output and a,b,c,d,e the set of constants.
Module performs something like the following operation:

```
y=(a*x)+(b*x)+(c*x)+(d*x)+(e*x); //separate adder and multiplier modules are used and this code itself is huge so just providing the idea.
```

Now I have used following method to choose the right value for the constants depending on the input: (Pseudo code)

```
module top (x,clk,y);
input clk;
input [31:0] x;

output [31:0] y;

if (x>=32'h08000000 && x<32'h0A000000) begin

localparam a = 32'h058B90C0; 
localparam b = 32'h193C9F60; 
localparam c = 32'h29AC1740; 
localparam d = 32'hA48B9440; 
localparam e = 32'h0B6392E0; 

end else if  (x>=32'h0A000000 && x<32'h0C000000) begin

localparam a = 32'h028A50C1; 
localparam b = 32'hE98B489C; 
localparam c = 32'h17402948; 
localparam d = 32'h9440E45B; 
localparam e = 32'h392E00AF; 

end

y=(a*x)+(b*x)+(c*x)+(d*x)+(e*x); // Module that computes using any of the above mentioned constant sets

endmodule
```

I get the following errors:

(1) "Unable to bind parameter".
(2) "Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: ((x)G(32'000010000....00))&& so on......"

My question is:

My user will give the input through x, right constants will be chosen, my module will calculate and provide the output. Just providing the right constants to the module is enough. How shall I do it? Ideas through pseudo code will be helpful for me.

Comment: @toolic I did try the your solution `reg [31:0] a,b,c,d,e;` and then `assign a = 32'h058B90C0; ` I am using icarus verilog to compile and seems like its always reporting `if (q>=32'h08000000 && q<32'h0A000000)` line as a faulty one.

Comment: please read about verilog syntax before attempting to do anything with it. Your sudo-code has nothing to do with verilog and does not fit into its semantics. Please read about variables, parameters, always blocks, generate blocks, ...

Answer (score -1):

I had to look up where localparam is allowed. You can define a localparam after a begin : < label >.
I tried it and found that (at least in Vivado) it passed and worked.

```
always @( a )
  if (a>=1)
  begin : a_be_1
     localparam P1 = 3;
     c = P1;
  end
  else
  begin : a_sm_1
     localparam P1 = 5;
     c = P1;
  end
```